# New slide in oven install

Tags: oven, remodeling

I’m Installing a new slide in GE Gas oven and the gas line is located higher on the wall than usual.
This is forcing the oven forward an extra inch.

Can I remove back plate so the oven sits more flush with  the wall and safely operate the oven?

Comment: We do not know what exactly the back plate is or how it effects your particular oven.

Comment: Can you include a picture of the back of the oven and gas line?

Comment: Yes, please see photo. The manufacturer parts list calls it a cover back ... it’s a plate on the back of the oven held on with screws and is considered part of the body of the oven.  Thanks!  

https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/spec/WB34X28992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't screw with the appliance, you'll kill your warranty when they send out a repairman...very likely with appliances today.

Your best approach would be to put an elbow on the gas line and send the line along the wall rather than straight out of it. If there isn't currently a shut-off valve behind the oven, then install one...unless the shut-off elsewhere is VERY easily accessible and ALWAYS clear.

Comment: Thank you, I am worried about blowing the warranty.

Comment: Agreed, +1. Your installation instructions will state minimum clearance requirements. Those minimums assume you will install the appliance as-built. Removing that back plate could result in worse than a nullified warranty; you could end up with your cabinet/kitchen/house in a smoldering heap...